# Route to new component with props on button click React

Tags: reactjs, button, hyperlink, routes, components

When the Button is clicked I need to pass new props the UnitOverview an go to the link "OeeUnitOverview". When I Go the link "OeeUnitOverview to component will load automatically.
I want to print the ID and name in the OeeUnitOverview class

```
<Button
  component={Link}
  to="OoeUnitOverview"
  // render={(props) => <UnitOverview id={5} name={"test"} {...props} />}
  // ///  <== not working
  variant="contained"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
>
  Detailscode
</Button>

class UnitOverview extends React.Component<IUnitProps> {
  constructor(props: IUnitProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // console.log("UnitOverview id " + this.state.name);
    console.log("id = " + this.props.id);
    console.log("name = " + this.props.name);
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>test</h1>;
  }
}
interface IUnitProps {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  history?: any;
  location?: any;
  match?: any;
}

export default UnitOverview;
```

Comment: It may help to provide us a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. What navigation/routing is being used? What are the extra props you want to send with the navigation?

Comment: I want to send a ID and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `react-router-dom`. With the `Link` component you can pass route state. [Link: to object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object).

```
<Button
  component={Link}
  to={{
    pathname: "OoeUnitOverview",
    state: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'test',
    },
  }}
  variant="contained"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
>
  Detailscode
</Button>
```

Then on the receiving route (the one rendering `UnitOverview`), ensure it has access to [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) or router context. The route state will be on the `location` prop/object.

```
this.props.location.state
// or props.location.state
// or const { state } = useLocation();
```

Based on the interface

```
interface IUnitProps {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  history?: any;
  location?: any;
  match?: any;
}
```

I will assume it is correctly receiving the route props. Use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to access the passed route state and handle any logic that depends on them.

```
class UnitOverview extends React.Component<IUnitProps> {
  constructor(props: IUnitProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      location: {
        state,
      },
    } = this.props;

    console.log("id = " + state.id);
    console.log("name = " + state.name);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>test</h1>;
  }
}
```

If you see error that `props.location` is undefined and you can't get to the state, then you can wrap the `UnitOverview` export with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component.

```
export default withRouter(UnitOverview);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225161/discussion-on-answer-by-drew-reese-route-to-new-component-with-props-on-button-c).